# Changing variable in datasource query

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, datasource

I have two dropdowns, where the second dropdown's options depend on what was selected in the first one. Both are bound to SqlDataSource with different queries. The SqlDataSource query of the second dropdown has a variable that is linked to the option selected in the first dropdown.

And so far this works - only on the default value. When the program is started up, the second dropdown options are correct according to the first dropdown having the first (default) item selected.

However, when I select a different item in the first list, the items in the second dropdown don't update.

I've tried several solutions. First, I made a SelectedIndexChanged method that fires when the first dropdown selection is changes. Something like this:

```
    protected void DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDown2.DataMember = DropDown1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

This doesn't work. I feel like when a datasource is bound, a refresh should be automatic, and require minimal coding. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to check the "Enable AutoPostBack" property of the first dropdown. This causes a postback to the server to occur if the selection is changed.